# AWS IoT SDK Java -Publishing a message on topic causes OutOfMemoryException -Tomcat

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tomcat7, aws-iot, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to publish a message on a topic using aws-java-sdk-iot using AWSIotDataClient's publish method on a tomcat server (7.0.70) on EC2 instance in us-east-1 region.

I tried with 2 different versions of the aws-java-sdk-iot (1.11.255 and 1.10.77)
Ref:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/tree/master/aws-java-sdk-iot

When the publish method is called I see the CPU utilization goes to 80% and I see OutOfMemory Errors in my application logs and catalina.out logs.
My tomcat memory settings are -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m

It would be great if any one can point me in the right direction or if I am missing something when constructing AWSIoTDataClient or doing something wrong.

Thanks in Advance.

Below is the snippet of the code when using 1.11.255 version of aws-java-sdk-iot:
The code is in a singleton class: sendMessageToTpoic is the method which gets invoked to send the message on topic.

```
public Boolean sendMessageToTopic(String messagePayLoad, String topic) throws IoTPublishException{
    Boolean result = false;
    logger.info("sendMessageToTopic MessagePayload: "+messagePayLoad+", topic: "+topic);
    try {
        PublishRequest request = new PublishRequest();
        ByteBuffer byteBufferMsg = stringToByteBuffer(messagePayLoad);
        request.setPayload(byteBufferMsg);
        request.setQos(1);
        request.setSdkClientExecutionTimeout(10000);
        request.setSdkRequestTimeout(10000);
        request.setTopic(topic);

        if(awsIotDataClient==null){
            awsIotDataClient= config();
        }
        awsIotDataClient.publish(request);

        logger.info("Publishing the request on the topic"+request);
        result =true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error sending message to the aws-iot-gateway"+messagePayLoad,e);
        throw new IoTPublishException(
                "UNABLE_TO_POST_MESSAGE_IN_IOT_TOPIC",
                "Unable to publish to topic: " + topic + ", for message: "
                        + messagePayLoad, e);
    }
    logger.info("Exit sendMessageToTopic: result: "+result,",messagePayLoad: "+messagePayLoad+", topic:"+topic);
    return result;
}

public  AWSCredentialsProvider populateCreds() throws AmazonClientException{
    AWSCredentials creds =null;
    try {
        if(instanceProvider==null){
            try {
                instanceProvider = new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(true);
                creds = instanceProvider.getCredentials();
                logger.debug("Creds : {} ",creds);

            }catch (AmazonClientException e) {
                logger.error("Error-AmazonClientException when loading AWS Creds from Instance Meta-Data ",e);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error-GenericException when loading AWS Creds from Instance Meta-Data ",e);
            }
            if(instanceProvider ==null || creds==null){
                profileProvider = new ProfileCredentialsProvider();
                logger.info("Loaded creds from aws.credentials file in default directory");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error-GenericException in populateCreds ",e);
        throw new AmazonClientException(
                "Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " +
                        "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct " +
                        "location (~/.aws/credentials), and is in valid format.",
                        e);
    }

    return ( (instanceProvider!=null && creds!=null)?instanceProvider:profileProvider);
}

protected  AWSIotDataClient config() throws Exception{
    try {
        //Loading Via populateCreds: InstanceCredentialsProvider or ProfileCredentialsProvider
        awsIotDataClient = (AWSIotDataClient) AWSIotDataClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(populateCreds())
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                .build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error-GenericException creating the AWSIotDataClient in config: ",e);
        throw e;
    }
    return awsIotDataClient;
}
```

Update: 02/12/2018: It was a tomcat maxpermsize issue but not with the AWS SDK.

Comment: did you try profiling your application and see the heap usage ?

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal I did profile the application with yourkit and I saw the heap size didn't max out but the CPU went to 80% to 100%

Comment: when you were profilling your application, that time did you get OOM error ? and were you profilling the tomcat JVM ?

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal Yes, When I profiled the application I got the OOM error and I added the profiler to tomcat JVM

Comment: its strange, can you attach report of your profile?

Comment: It was a tomcat maxpermsize issue but not with the AWS SDK